# How to send Image from Imageview to a Server

Tags: java, android

I am making SignUp form which includes many fields along with Profile Picture. I have converted everything to a string except the Image. I am unable to understand that How can I send Image to server along with other string values when someone clicks on the SignUp button.

Following is my source code for your perusal:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class SignUp extends Activity {
    ImageView imageView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.signup);


        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagecontact);
    }
    public void onGalleryClick(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE),1);
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            if(requestCode == 1)
                imageView.setImageURI(data.getData());
        }
    }


    public void onSignUpClick(View view) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.BT_signup) {
            EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ED_bakeryname);
            EditText maail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ED_emailaddress);
            EditText number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ED_mobilenumber);
            EditText address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ED_postaladd);
            EditText pass1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ED_pass1);
            EditText pass2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ED_pass2);
            ImageView imageView1 =(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imagecontact);


            String namestring = name.getText().toString();
            String mailstring = name.getText().toString();
            String numberstring = name.getText().toString();
            String addressstring = name.getText().toString();
            String pass1string = name.getText().toString();
            String pass2string = name.getText().toString();


            if (!pass1string.equals(pass2string)) {
                //popup msg

                Toast pword = Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Passwords don't match!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                pword.show();
            }
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: please clear your problem ?

Comment: how do i add th imageview to a string?

Comment: You don't add an ImageView to a String.

Comment: Is you trying to say that you have add text on the image ?

Comment: Is it string or textView?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils,so when the user clicks on sign up it will show?

Comment: as you can see in the code i have different textviews and converted them to stings,i added an Imageview for a profile picture ...now my question is should i add it to a string to under on signUp click? and how do i do it

Comment: @NickyNiq your question really confusing ......please clear what you want ,.

Comment: Are you trying to ask, How to check whether user already selected Profile Image or not? or Are you trying to ask, How to send Profile Image to the server?

Comment: @Yasir Tahir,yes...i didnt know how to ask the question well...new to android Dev,sending to the server to be exact..sorry for the confusion

Comment: What do you want? How to check whether user already selected Profile Image or not?

Comment: Or How to send Profile Image to the server?

Comment: how to send profile image to sever.

Comment: Okay we believe you're new to android. But you should know how to convey your question (all of the things that are floating in your mind) to others. No-one can answer you unless you ask the question clearly. We all are humans can't read others mind.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are trying to convert your image into base64 String.

From your code, you can first get the image from imageView:

```js
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView1.getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
```

Then convert the bitmap to a byte array:

```js
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();
```

Then you can get the string:

```js
String image_byte=String.valueOf(byte[] byteArray);
```

Then ofcourse you can jus pass the string like the rest of the other detail. Then afterwards you can get the string back from the server and decode it into an imageView.